# Showing/hiding items - listview

Tags: android, listview, visibility

I have a special question which i havent't found the answer. I can't deal with this problem. 
So... is there any way to hide or show items(images) dynamically on `ListView`?

I mean, after tap on toolbar menu item called "Edit", on `ListView` next to the texts should appear images. When user click on this image, this text should be removed from `ListView` and database. And, after tap on "Done", images that have previously appeared should gone.

I spent all night for this and I haven't found the answer, so guys please help me!

I have this:

[image]

And want this after click on Edit:

[image]

That's part of my Adapter (extends from BaseAdapter)

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(todo.get(position));
        ImageView circleImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circleImage);
        Picasso.with(mActivity).load(R.drawable.circle_image).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(circleImage);
    }
        if(editMode){
            circleImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else circleImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return convertView;
}

public void setMode(boolean editMode){
    this.editMode=editMode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

onOptionItemSelected from MainActivity:

```
else if(id == R.id.edit){
        mToDoFragment = new ToDOFragment();
        mFToDoFragment.setEditable(true);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
```

And, last part from ToDoFragment:

```
public void setEditable(boolean editable){
    mFavouritesListAdapter.setMode(editable);
}
```

After that, I'm getting such beutiful NullPointerException :(

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void adapters.ToDoListAdapter.setMode(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Yes I can help you but let me know what you have developed. Show me some stuff.

Comment: I mean it is possible. Simply you have to manage the raw data set and edit and remove options should apply on dataset. The dataset is bind with your list and call notifiy dataset appropriately when needed.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar  added two photos :)

Comment: You want to remove the item from the listview when you click on [x] icon correct.

Comment: Thats right and i know how to do that. I don't know how set visibility of these circles after when user press Edit button.

Comment: Do not call this method directly ToDoListAdapter.setMode(boolean)

Comment: I see that you change the fragment. or try to create the fragment.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar ok, I have done this, but... nothing happened. I see in logcat that the variable editMode changes, but listview is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please follow the blow steps. I hope it will help you.

1. First you have flag that indicate that current mode for example the list view in edit mode or in normal mode (view mode)
2. After define the mode. Take the array list with your model or object. bind you array list with `BaseAdapter`. I guess you are using the `ListView`. If you are using the `RecyclerView` then the process or logic will remain the same.
3. In inside the `getView(....)`. Define you layout using `LayoutInflater` 
   After checking the convert-view is not null and inflating the layout.
   Put the logic for check the flag of mode.
4. Check whether the mode is edit mode or normal view mode. If edit then show the [x] icon for each row item otherwise hide/gone the image view.
5. If the mode is edit when click on [x] image view remove position of the model or object from the dataset that is bind with the `BaseAdapter`. And call `notifyDatasetChanged()`. This will refresh the list view and remove the item from listview.
6. If edit mode is complete and user click on "Done" Option from menu item. Then simply change the flag of mode from edit to done mode. call again `notifyDatasetChanged()` method of your `BaseAdapter`

That's it. You done let me know if you have any query.